# Rest API call during Azure AD B2C SignIN in Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to do Rest API calls during Sign In in Azure AD B2C policy?

I want to add few properties in claims at the time when user sign in to the application. I can see that it is possible while sign up
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom

But is it possible during Sign In as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom policy, it's very similar to Sign-up. You create the technical profile for your REST endpoint and use it either as a ValidationTechnicalProfile in your 'sign-in' technical profile or add it as an orchestration step - depends what you want to do. 
Any particular problem you are facing while adding this in your sign-in journey?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issue while I am adding sing-in journey.
can call REST API successfully and can received other input values except password value.

Below is the output result from my function app:

GetExternalSystemIdOnLogin got request body:

```
{
  "email": "xxxx@test.com",
  "objectId": "dec23a2c-64c3-49c4-9943-4cfe0cffa0ed"
}
```